How to add or import font family with all font weight in shadow root element that not effect from the outside
How to add or import font family with all font weight in shadow root element that not effect from the outside
In shadow root element css added below code
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap');
or
In shadow root element using link

It does not work because in consuming app font weight 500 missing i.e. in head tag inside body
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

Bold code is shadow element and Italic code in consuming app, problem is that consuming app is override font weight but requirement is in shadow root what font family and font weight added, should not effect from outside the code.
I tried many ways like font family used in local folder of shadow element and using css tried load but it effected from outside the code
